# Basic jQuery popup using geolocation

Tags: jquery, geolocation, popup

The function of this popup is to first figure out where the user is, (in the US) using geolocation. If they are in fact in the US the popup will then show, but it isn't popping up. Not sure if I am calling the right function?

```
<script>
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {

    jQuery('#city').html(location.city);
    jQuery('#region-code').html(location.region_code);
    jQuery('#region-name').html(location.region_name);
    jQuery('#areacode').html(location.areacode);
    jQuery('#ip').html(location.ip);
    jQuery('#zipcode').html(location.zipcode);
    jQuery('#longitude').html(location.longitude);
    jQuery('#latitude').html(location.latitude);
    jQuery('#country-name').html(location.country_name);
    jQuery('#country-code').html(location.country_code);
  }
} );

    </script>

 <script>
jQuery.ajax( { 
  url: '//freegeoip.net/json/', 
  type: 'POST', 
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(location) {

    if (location.country_code === 'CA') {

      jQuery.show(jQuery('#message'));
    }
  }
} );
</script>
<div style="display:none;">
  <div id="message" style="padding:30px;">
    <h1>Hola!</h1>
    <p>You are in US</p>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: Try `jQuery('#message').show();`
But why do you have to create two same async request here?

Looks like you can add logic for showing popup in first request success handler.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're in Canada, wanting to test to make sure it works for the US? Or do you want to trick people in Canada into thinking they're in the US?

You should be using:

```
jQuery('#message').parent().show();
```

Since you set the parent element of `#message` to `display:none;` instead of the `#message` element itself.

Here's a working Fiddle, though if you're in Canada, you'll have to change back to `location.country_code === 'CA'`: https://jsfiddle.net/3wcvh7L5/

Another thing to mention - this does not work with AdBlock Plus installed on Chrome...